# Adding numbers in the beginning of each line in a file

Tags: java, bluej

I have a file with some random code (can use any other random file) I want to add the number of lines at the start of each line. 
For example:

```
1.
2.
3.
```

etc.
Also removing any blank lines and keep numbering the lines correctly. 
here's my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    boolean foundException = false;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        try {
            System.out.print("Please enter input file name: ");
            String fileName = keyboard.next();
            File inputFile = new File("inputfile.txt"); 
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("inputfile.txt"));
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new File("inputfile.txt"));

            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                line = line.trim();
                if(line.length() > 0)
                    out.println(line);
            }

            for( int i = 1; i < inputFile.length(); i++){
                System.out.println( i + "." + inputFile);
            }
            foundException = false;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException x) {
            System.out.println("File does not exist");
            foundException = true;
        }

    } while (foundException);
}
}
```

but the result I get is very large number of lines + the file name like " 300. inputfile.txt "
the whole file has about 25 lines but I'm getting 500+ lines, I'm assuming it's counting every word after a space?
I have another question about the file, I'm not sure if im calling the file correctly in the code which is "inputfile.txt" the file location is inside the folder of the project.
thanks for your time.

Comment: `File.length()` returns “The length, **in bytes**, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname,…” (my emphasis). No wonder you got very high numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can keep all lines in memory, that helps for writing to the same file:

```
    Path inputFile = Paths.get("inputfile.txt");
    Charset charset = Charset.getDefault();
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(inputFile, charset);
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
            Files.newBufferedWriter(inputFile, charset,
                StandardOpenOptions.TRUNCATE_EXISTING))) {
        int lineno = 0;
        for (String line : lines) {
            ++lineno;
            out.printf("%d. %s%n", lineno, line);
        }
    }
```

You can use a fixed Charset like Charset.UTF_8, and a fixed line break instead of `%n` like `\r\n` (Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Initialization of input stream will remove file content, so you can read file content first, and then write to it as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        boolean foundException = false;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Please enter input file name: ");
                String fileName = keyboard.next();
                File inputFile = new File("inputfile.txt");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("inputfile.txt"));
                ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

                int lineNum = 1;
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    line = line.trim();
                    if (line.length() > 0) {
                        lines.add(lineNum + "." + line);
                        lineNum++;
                    }
                }
                PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new File("inputfile.txt"));
                for (String line : lines)
                    out.println(line);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException x) {
                System.out.println("File does not exist");
                foundException = true;
            }

        } while (foundException);
    }
```

And method name called on file object does not return number of lines in file. I will refer to docs:

> The length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname,
>   or `0L` if the file does not exist.  Some operating systems
>   may return `0L` for pathnames denoting system-dependent
>   entities such as devices or pipes.

Comment: I've tested the code, when I run it and put the file name it does not do anything but terminate the program (assuming that I've put an exist file), is that because the file does not exist or I don't have anything to print it? , I want it to read the file I have but can't seem to be able to do that, do I have to make another file for PrintStream or what does that object exactly do.

Comment: When program terminates, try to check the file, whether lines number were added. If you want to print file content to console, do it in loop while writing or reading, or simply iterate arraylist.